# Parsing DateTime with timezone offset with JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net, datetimeoffset

I make a call to a web service, which returns an item, one property of which is:

```
"startDate":"/Date(1398859200000+1100)/"
```

In my C# representation, I have:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate {get; set;}
}
```

In my unit test, I have the following assertion

```
var expectation = 
    new DateTimeOffset(2014, 04, 30, 12, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0, 11, 0, 0));

Assert.That(specialOfferContent.End, Is.EqualTo(expectiation).Within(1).Seconds);
```

(not sure if there's a better way to assert this...)

If deserialize this from JSON using (without specifying DateParseHandling), the result I get is:

> Expected: 04/30/2014 12:00:00 +11:00 +/- 00:00:01
>   But was:  04/30/2014 13:00:00 +01:00

Alternatively, if I specify DateParseHandling as `DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset` I get this:

> Expected: 04/30/2014 12:00:00 +11:00 +/- 00:00:01
>   But was:  04/30/2014 23:00:00 +11:00

My question is, what am i doing wrong?
It is ignoring the +1100 part of the date when I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is incorrect, basically.

The value you've given *is* 04/30/2014 23:00:00 +11:00 - because it's UTC 04/30/2014T12:00:00 (as verified with [Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/)), but with a local offset of +11 hours. So the local time is 11pm.

In your input, there are two pieces of data:

- 1398859200000: The number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (this will be the same around the world, at a given instant)
- +1100: The local offset from UTC

It's important to distinguish the two parts - in particular understanding that the first part is *not* affected by the time zone.

Comment: I'm editing my comment each time you edit your answer.. haha! Anyway.. I was using the Epoch Converter, and think that's where my confusion stemmed from - how can I *assert* that the date time offset has been parsed with the offset (in this instance +1100)

Comment: @Alex: You'd create it as `new DateTimeOffset(2014, 04, 30, 23, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(0, 11, 0, 0));` - because the `DateTimeOffset` constructor takes the *local* time and the offset from UTC.

Comment: Thanks Jon, by *local* time do you mean time on the (in this case) developer machine... for example, if a developer in, let's say, Singapore, checked out the code and run the unit test, it would fail?

Comment: @Alex: It's the local time represented by the value `/Date(1398859200000+1100)/`. So it's presumably local to whatever produced that value. It doesn't depend on the system you're running the *parsing* code on.